# global variable is not detected when using jquery but no error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, frontend

Hi there :) This might seem like a silly question, but my global variable doesn't work in a jquery function.

Here I created a variable outside the function, and I named it "css":

```
var css = ' {width: 200px; font-family: "Futura", sans-serif; text-align: center; flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0; padding: 8px 10px;}';
```

In the function that follows the declaration I called the "css" variable in a jquery function:

```
function create() {

var Elements = "";

var divId = "num";

for (var i = 0 + initial; i < 7 + initial; i++) {
  divId += i;
  Elements += '<div id=' + divId + '>' + i + '</div>';

  $('<style>' + '#' + css + '</style>').appendTo(document.head);
}

var container = document.getElementById("row");
container.innerHTML = Elements;

}
```

But the output is not styled as it should. The weird thing is I don't get any error of undefined variable either.
And everything works just fine when I put the variable declaration inside the `function create()`. But I don't want it that way because I would have multiple functions similar to `function create()`, and it would be more efficient if I just declare the variable once.

I suspect it's because of the nature of jquery? Any help?

Comment: looks like your adding `# { ... }` as style, are you sure it works without an id?

Comment: @ChrisLi oops i forgot "divId". It works after I add it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Chris Li's comment solved your question but there was no answer created and it doesn't seem like this question is going to be closed.

If Chris Li decides to create an answer I will remove mine.

Also along with his answer, I strongly recommend against naming a variable `Elements`. Variables in JavaScript should not start with an uppercase letter. To see the variable naming conventions, check out the section titled 'Variable Names' in this [W3Schools JavaScript Style Guide](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)

I always find it's easier to see code working in a snippet so I created one below to demonstrate your problem.

```js
// Use const for variables that don't change and let for local variables instead of var
// if your browser environment supports it.
const css = '{width: 200px; font-family: "Futura", sans-serif; text-align: center; flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0; padding: 8px 10px;}';

function create() {

    // I have no idea what `initial` refers to so I'll just use a placeholder here.
    let initial = 0;

    let elements = '';
  
    let divId = 'num';
  
    for (let i = 0 + initial; i < 7 + initial; i++) {
  
        divId += i;
    
        elements += '<div id=' + divId + '>' + i + '</div>';
    
        // The above line can also be written using template literals.
        // elements += `<div id=${divId}>${i}</div>';
    
        $('<style>' + '#' + divId + css + '</style>').appendTo(document.head);
        
    }
    
    const container = document.getElementById('row');
    
    container.innerHTML = elements;
    
}

// Call the create function to see it in action.
create();
```

```html
<div id='row'></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```